# Convert decimal time to hh:mm format with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I have a script which returns a decimal value to represent time. I need to convert the decimal time value to hh:mm (i.e: 90 minutes should be repreesnted as 1:30. Attached is my current script.

```
function Convert() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById("sum").value;
    var hours = minutes / 60;
    document.getElementById('total').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('sum').value = minutes;

    var minutes = document.getElementById("sum_1").value;
    var hours = minutes / 60;
    document.getElementById('total_1').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('sum_1').value = minutes;
}
```

Comment: there is a problem on this issue between firefox/chrome/etc.
i used moment.js in my project.

Comment: So what does not work? And why do you do the nearly same thing twice?

Comment: Bergi.. Right now this script calulates time in decimal format. Example: 90 minutes appears as 1.5 ... I need it to be 1:30 and not sure how to midify this script.  The reason you see "sum" and "sum_1" is because the totals are gathers from 2 different places. Eiter way if I can get one to work/display in the correct format I can do the other.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only can assume that you forgot to [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) the `hours` and to apply [modululus 60](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) on the `minutes` to get the result you expected.